# Session variable in another page

Tags: php, oracle

I am doing a programming in PHP and Database, what I am trying to do is passing the session variable into another page, but the problem is I cant see the value on the other page here is my selector code

```
<form method="post" action="monitorIndex.php">
                            <?php      
                                $projectParse = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT DISTINCT PROJECT_NAME FROM MASTER_DRAWING '
                                        . 'ORDER BY PROJECT_NAME ASC');
                                oci_execute($projectParse);

                                echo '<select name="cd-dropdown" id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">';
                                    echo '<OPTION VALUE="">PROJECT SELECT</OPTION>';
                                    while($row = oci_fetch_array($projectParse,OCI_ASSOC)){
                                        $projectName = $row ['PROJECT_NAME'];
                                        echo "<OPTION VALUE='$projectName'>$projectName</OPTION>";
                                    }
                                echo '</select>';
                            ?>
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit">
                            </form>
```

and the acceptor is this,

```
<?php 

$_SESSION['cd-dropdown'] = $_POST['cd-dropdown'];

?>

<h1><?php $_SESSION['cd-dropdown']; ?></h1>
```

I cant see the value in h1, please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing an `echo`;

```
<h1><?php echo $_SESSION['cd-dropdown']; ?></h1>
```

BTW, you should've started the session that way `session_start();` somewhere or your code won't work

#### Edit

See comment below:

```
$_SESSION['cd-dropdown'] = 
                          isset($_POST['cd-dropdown']) ? $_POST['cd-dropdown'] : 
                          isset($_SESSION['cd-dropdown']) ? $_SESSION['cd-dropdown'] : '';
```

or (more readable)

```
if(isset($_POST['cd-dropdown'])) {
    $_SESSION['cd-dropdown'] = $_POST['cd-dropdown'];
}
elseif(!isset($_SESSION['cd-dropdown'])) {
    $_SESSION['cd-dropdown'] = '';
}
```

Remember that I don't know the logic behind so you have to "fix" logic yourself (i.e.: what about "old" posted values? Have to be accepted or deleted?)

Comment: One more question, if I refresh the page, I lost that variable. How to keep that variable intact when I refresh that target page

Comment: @uDonCallisto should I use ';' instead of ':' ? because its showing an error

Comment: @user3736689: no should be correct syntax... could you attach error?

Comment: I put this code after session_start(),

$_SESSION['cd-dropdown'] =  isset($_POST['cd-dropdown']) ? $_POST['cd-dropdown'] : 
                          isset($_SESSION['cd-dropdown']) ? $_SESSION['cd-dropdown'] : '';

and the problem is the value is not showing at all now.

I call the variable by using this `<h1><?php echo $_SESSION['cd-dropdown']; ?></h1>`

Comment: @user3736689: maybe isn't the right place to put it... If we don't have *real* code we can't help you ...